# error on create new config database for sharepoint wih New-SPConfigurationDatabase

Tags: sql-server, windows, sharepoint, sql-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010

I want setup SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008. When I want to create new configuration database with this command:

```
    New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName "SPConfigDB" -AdministrationContentDatabaseName "SPAdminContentDB" -DatabaseServer "DESKTOP-54TIM0H\dadkh" -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString "mypass" -AsPlainText -force) -FarmCredentials (Get-Credential)

run it in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell I have error:

New-SPConfigurationDatabase : Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at DESKTOP-54TIM0H\dadkh. The database migh
t not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.
At line:1 char:28
+ New-SPConfigurationDatabase <<<<  -DatabaseName "SPConfigDB" -AdministrationContentDatabaseName "SPAdminContentDB" -Dat
abaseServer "DESKTOP-54TIM0H\dadkh" -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString "mypass" -AsPlainText -force) -FarmCredent
ials (Get-Credential)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase) [New-S
   PConfigurationDatabase], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase
```

I [follow this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service) but the problem not solved.

[image: database list]

I create a database with name "SPConfigDB" but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was IIS!
I check status of IIS and it was not active! so I enable it and problem solved!

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. I can't see how IIS could possibly be related to this MSSQL connection for SharePoint.

I believe what you encountered here is Correlation, not Causation.  I say this as someone who is deep in the bowels of a "cannot connect to database master" issue right now, and I duped myself with several assumptions around correlation that turned out not to be true.